# MongoDB sum of two nested field is less than some ratio of another nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've documents as follows:

```
{
   id: "14530529:V10AFRIN2018-AED15C",
   daily_log:{
      downloaded: 12345,
      uploaded:   10000,
      total:      50000
   }
}
```

I need to find documents if **sum** of **daily_log.downloaded** and **daily_log.uploaded** is greater than 80% percentage of **daily_log.total**

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: You can try `db.col.find({"$expr":{"$gt":[{"$add":["daily_log.downloaded", "daily_log.uploaded"]}, {"$multiply":[0.8, "$daily_log.total"]}]}});` in 3.6

Comment: Thank you @Veeram. Do you have a suggestion for MongoDB 3.2?

Comment: Np.Wrap the logic in [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) from aggregation. Something like `db.col.aggregate({
      $redact: {
        $cond: {
          if: {"$gt":[{"$add":["daily_log.downloaded"‌​, "daily_log.uploaded"]}, {"$multiply":[0.8, "$daily_log.total"]}]},
          then: "$$KEEP",
          else: "$$PRUNE"
        }
      }
    })`